# Mandrill rule to BCC email to another recipient

Tags: mandrill

Is it possible to add a rule to Mandrill that will BCC the email to a different email address for every outgoing mail? I don't have access to the code so I'm hoping there's a way on the dashboard.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There's no 'rule' to do this, but you can achieve it using the Settings -> Sending Defaults.

Add the email address you want to the 'Send a copy of every email to this address' option.

It does mean it sends to every email sent through the system, rather than messages that meet criteria set in a rule.